# How to display Latin-1 characters in Android app

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I have to fetch text from an online database encoded in Latin-1 charset and every special Latin character (i.e. à, ò, ù, è...) was displayed with black squares with a "?" inside.

How can i display this correctly?

Luckily i found an answer after a couple of hours and i want to share it with you all.
Read below for my solution

Comment: "à" is a regular character, nothing "special" about it.

Comment: i define it "special" because it wouldn't be rendered correctly if i don't do anything "special" to display it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution was really simple but i haven't thought about it, but it has the benefit of being really simple to understand and implement. In fact, here is the code:

```
mIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream(),"ISO-8859-1"));
```

this way, all the incoming strings from the Latin-1 server will be decoded correctly and will be displayed perfectly on android TextViews